# Implementing Hover Effects, Adding Buttons, and Improving Design for an Expanding Content Card in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on an Expanding Content Card for a WordPress website using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I have developed it without relying on any CSS frameworks. I have a few questions regarding its functionality and design:

1. How can I implement a feature where the description text (.wdg-description) appears just below the title when the user hovers over it?
2. I would like to add a button that is only visible when the user hovers over the content card. How can I achieve this?
3. I've noticed that the current design doesn't align perfectly with the mocks. Are there any suggestions or best practices to improve the design?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Code

```js
let userImages = document.querySelectorAll(".user-image");
userImages.forEach(function (e) {
  e.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    userImages.forEach(function (e) {
      e.classList.remove("active");
    });
    e.classList.add("active");
  });
  e.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    e.classList.remove("active");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #10172b;
}
.image-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.image-wrapper .user-image img {
  width: 345px;
  transition: all 0.7s ease; /*   will-change: height; */
}
.image-wrapper .user-image.active {
  width: 60%;
}
.image-wrapper .user-image {
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 450px;
  width: 21%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
.image-wrapper .user-image:hover {
  width: 60%;
}
.image-wrapper .user-image.active img {
  height: 100%;
}
.wdg-header-text {
  font-family: Poppins, Arial, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 33px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.wdg-image {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: -20px;
}
.wdg-description {
  width: 345px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  font-family: Poppins, Arial, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.purple {
  background-color: #6d38f1;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  width: 250px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <div class="user-image" style="background: #293346">
    <div class="wdg-header">
      <p class="wdg-header-text">Services</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wdg-description">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</div>
    <div class="wdg-image"> <img src="https://i.ibb.co/nLqKR5S/services-prix.png" alt="Services" />
    </div>
    <button class="purple">Learn More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="user-image" style="background:#293346">
    <div class="wdg-header">
      <p class="wdg-header-text">Warehouse</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wdg-description">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</div>
    <div class="wdg-image"> <img src="https://i.ibb.co/WvbjHwh/warehouse-prix.png" alt="Warehouse" />
    </div>
    <button class="purple">Learn More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="user-image" style="background:#293346">
    <div class="wdg-header">
      <p class="wdg-header-text">Warehouse</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wdg-description">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</div>
    <div class="wdg-image"> <img src="https://i.ibb.co/k61m60K/iiot-prix.png" alt="Warehouse" />
    </div>
    <button class="purple">Learn More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: 1st screen without mouseover]

[image: 2nd Screen on Mouseover]

Are there any suggestions or best practices to improve the design?

Comment: Please **post your code alongside your question** so that the question remains relevant even in case the third-party website is unavailable. Additionally, StackOverflow features [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/13561410).